# NextJs - Page shows before redirect

Tags: next.js

I am having some issues in next.js when clicking on a navigation buttons and redirecting to a new page.

I have navigation with links like this one below:

```
          <button key={index}>
            <a
              href={url}
            >
              {text}
            </a>
          </button>
```

For example, route where  element points is /about. When I click on a button, "about" page will flash for a second or less and after that redirect to that page will happen. I cannot figure why is that happening

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in Link component?

Comment: What is the difference? You think that it will solve the issue?

Comment: The difference is that `next/link` enables client-side transitions between routes, unlike the `<a>` tag that fully reloads the page from the server.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the built-in component of nextjs to navigate on the client side see: [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

```
<Link href="/about">about<Link>
```

Comment: What is the difference? You think that it will solve the issue? Can I wrap <button> over that component?

Comment: @Denis2310 "Client-side transitions between routes can be enabled via the Link component exported by next/link." yes you can. you can even do a <Link href="/about"><a>Link<a></Link>

Comment: @DaveInoc You may want to update your answer to nest the `<a>` tag inside the `<Link>` component, i.e. `<Link href="/about"><a>Link<a></Link>`. The `Link` component should still have an `<a>` as a direct child.